# Forcibly logout user using Spring security when trying to login for the 2nd time in the same browser

Tags: spring-security

I'm authenticating the users of my application using Google Oauth.
When a user tries to login (using a new tab on the same browser) without logging out, I want to forcibly logout the user from their first session.

I see a new JSESSIONID for the 2nd login in my browser,but I still see the cookies from the 1st login.
I'm also seeing the attributes stored in HttpSession for the 1st login user. So the cookies and HttpSession are for sure not getting cleared, but I don't know if the first authentication has been invalidated upon the second login.
Can any of you point me to the method that I need to call to forcibly logout the user from their first session when they try to login again? I can clear the cookies and invalidate the HttpSession in the same method.

Here is my current code for Spring security using Oauth.

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
         .csrf()
         .disable()
         .authorizeRequests()     
         .antMatchers( "/error", "/login.html", "/images/**", "/styles/**")
         .permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/request.html").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
     .antMatchers(.....)
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .logout()
         .invalidateHttpSession(true)
     .clearAuthentication(true)
     .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","roles","username") 
         .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
             
                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,                         HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication authentication) throws                           IOException, ServletException {
                    
                    
                        response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
                    
                }
         })
         .and()
         .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                          .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                                 )
                 .loginPage("/login.html") 
                         .failureUrl("/loginFailure")
                         .successHandler(customOauth2SuccessHandler)
                     )
 //Updated with session management code
.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
            .sessionConcurrency((concurrency) -> 
             concurrency.maximumSessions(1)
                 //.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

                ))
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough room to put this in as a comment. Hence I'm posting it here.

**Findings on maximumSessions(1) for Oauth2 project -**
I followed the instructions mentioned in the link below  and was able to get maxSessions(1) to work with oauth2. It appears that Oauth2 requires a custom implementation of Spring Security’s SessionRegistry interface and I used the JdbcIndexedSessionRepository to persist the sessions to a MySQL database. From what I understood of the documentation, the sessions need to be persisted to a datastore only for applications that are running in a clustered environment since each node of the cluster may not be aware of the sessions on another node.  I'm not running my Spring Boot Oauth application in a clustered environment. So it is still not clear to me as to why the default concurrency session control provided by spring security(the link shared by Darren)  did not work for me.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions

Here is the working code for maximumSessions(1) in case it helps anyone

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig <S extends Session> {

private final String errorMessage = "Your session has expired. Please try logging in again !" ;

@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private CustomOauth2SuccessHandler customOauth2SuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S> sessionRepository;

public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<S> sessionRegistry() 
{
    return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(this.sessionRepository);
}
    
//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
         .csrf()
         .disable()
         .authorizeRequests()     
         .antMatchers("/login.html", "/images/**", "/styles/**")
         .permitAll()
         .antMatchers(...)
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .logout()
         .invalidateHttpSession(true)
         .clearAuthentication(true)
         .deleteCookies(...) 
         .logoutSuccessHandler(....)
         .and()
         .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> { 
                oauth2
               .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                                    .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                                 )
               .loginPage("/login.html") 
               .failureUrl("/loginFailure")
               .successHandler(customOauth2SuccessHandler) ;
                            }
        )
        //Required to handle concurrent sessions
        .sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .sessionRegistry(this.sessionRegistry())
                        .expiredUrl("/login.html?errorMessage=" + errorMessage)     
        )
        ;
        
        return http.build();
}
```

**Findings regarding my original question**
I have already posted that as comments

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security should have you covered if I'm understanding the question,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions

> If you wish to place constraints on a single user’s ability to log in to your application, Spring Security supports this out of the box with the following simple additions. First, you need to add the following listener to your configuration to keep Spring Security updated about session lifecycle events:

```java
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

and update config,

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .maximumSessions(1)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

> This will prevent a user from logging in multiple times - a second login will cause the first to be invalidated.

The link discusses more configurations (and provides a test to validate) on only allowing the first session etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Darren. What you shared with me makes sense, but I couldn't get it to work. Not sure if it's because I'm authenticating  using oauth.  I went thru the doc and used the exact code that you shared. I also tried the below

Comment: I also tried the below which is mentioned in 'Maximum Sessions Prevent Login sample' in the docs.                                                     http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionConcurrency(concurrency -> 
                  concurrency.maximumSessions(1)
                  .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                  .expiredUrl("/error.html") 
              )                                                                                                   Will need to research this some more and see if it's due to oauth.

Comment: OAuth is your authentication mechanism, it isn't involved in your authorization or session mgmt. There's likely diferent issues. Once the Oauth2 flow completes its job is essentially done.

Comment: Yes, I understand , Darren. It was a guess since things didn't work. I looked into this more today. It works across browsers, but not across browser tabs(which was my original question). I logged in as user1 on the first tab and set some session attributes. I didn't log out. Next, I logged in as user2 on the second tab. I will still able to access the session attributes that were set for user1. As I mentioned in my question, a new JSESSIONID does get created for user2, but the HttpSession does not get invalidated. So I'm still able to access the session attributes set for user1.

Comment: This is what I want - When user2 logs in on the 2nd browser tab, spring invalidates the user1 authentication. I want to invalidate the HttpSession, delete all the cookies sent by the browser and only return back the cookies that are relevant to user 2(user 2's role is different than user 1). I put this logic in a CustomOauth2SuccessHandler since Spring did not do it automatically. Thanks again for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Here's another update. I tested maximumSessions(1) with a normal formlogin project and it worked as expected(i.e. across 2 different browsers). I used the exact same syntax for sessionManagement in my Oauth project and maximumSessions(1) did not work. I was able to login with the same userid in both chrome and firefox. So the userid had 2 sessions. I know it's hard to believe. I will try to update my question with the revised code if stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: Here's an update. I posted a question to the spring session team on GitHub. They have asked me to use the below link in order to get maximumSessions to work with oauth.  This requires some setup since they are persisting the session to some storage(like a database or redis). If I manage to get it to work, I will post a message here  
 https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions